# In the new Facebook where can I see my list of Friend Requests?

Tags: facebook

In the old version of Facebook I could see a list of who I have "Friend Requested"; where is that in the new version?  I want to know who accepted my request or who just deleted my request.

Comment: "New" as of when? Facebook has gone through a number of redesigns since this question was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Facebook help](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=130936266984832#How-do-I-view-friend-requests-I%27ve-sent-that-are-still-pending?-Can-I-see-which-requests-haven%27t-yet-been-accepted?):

> There's currently no place on the site where you can see all your sent pending requests. However, if you go to someone's timeline you can tell your friend status based on the following.
>
> - If you see Add as Friend, then you don't have a friend request pending.
> - If you see Awaiting friend confirmation, you'll know that you've sent a request that hasn't yet been confirmed.
> - If you see the Remove friend link, you'll know you've both confirmed your friendship.

Answer (score 3):

There is a loophole to see pending friend requests on Facebook Timeline. Although Facebook does show you with all the friend requests received, there is no direct means to access the request you have sent from your account. But you can still keep track of them using the Facebook’s “*[Download Your Information](http://www.sociobits.org/2013/04/view-your-pending-friend-requests-on-facebook-timeline-may-2013.html)*” option. 
Follow:

1. Go to your '**Account Settings**'
2. Click on '**Download a Copy of your Facebook data**' on bottom of page.
3. Select '**expanded archive**' from the link below.
4. After entering your Password, click on '**Start My Archive**'
5. Once the archive is ready, you will receive an email. Now you need to download the    archive from the link. (Usually takes 1 to 2 hours)
6. Extract downloaded zip file and Open **index.html**
7. Then navigate to “**Pending friend requests**” link. Click that link, now you can see the whole pending friend requests list on 'Pending Sent Friend Requests' head. It will also shows you the 'Pending Received Friend Requests'. You can also view friends whom you have deleted from your account.

You're done!

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2013, you can now see all sent friend requests in the Facebook Activity Log. Just click on the **"Activity Log"** button on the top right of your profile page, or browse to /www.facebook.com/yourusername/allactivity and you'll see them all.

Comment: But I think, activity log doesn't show old sent friend requests.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook finally got the option to see the full pending request visiting the following link for the list:

https://m.facebook.com/friends/requests/outgoing

Answer (score 0):

Go to Activity log > more > friends. There you can see friend requests sent and can see if they are accepted or any other action you may want to take..